# google cloud sql second generation repair mysql.proc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm migrating to google cloud second generation but the table mysql.proc is damaged and when I try: REPAIR TABLE mysql.proc I get this error:

ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

How can i repar the proc table?